# Como faço URL Amigável + Redirecionamento 301 com .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável, redirecionamento-de-url

Eu tenho um site com milhares de páginas sem URL amigável, então quero colocar esse recurso..

Meu site atualmente está assim: https://www.meusite.com.br/?pag=videos Eu quero ele assim: https://www.meusite.com.br/videos

Eu segui esse caminho e funciona!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?pag=$1
```

Porém, as milhares de páginas ainda continuam com o link antigo e eu não vou conseguir mudar manualmente, então pensei em fazer o redirecionamento 301 via .htaccess, mas não consigo entender expressões regulares para unificar a url amigável acima + o redirecionamento 301 nos links abaixo:

```
https://www.meusite.com.br/?pag=noticias
https://www.meusite.com.br/?pag=noticias-exibe&news=nova-noticia-aqui
```

Eu dei uma olhada no artigo da [AgenciaMestre](https://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/redirecionamento-301-url-parametros-htacess-rewritecond/) que é mais ou menos o que eu preciso, porém, quando eu misturo os links antigos com os novos, fica algo assim e cada vez que eu vou clicando nestes links antigos, vão somando mais parametros aos links iniciais...

```
https://www.meusite.com.br/videos?pag=noticias?pag=videos?pag=dicas
```